# Echo specific result from a function

Tags: php, mysql, function, joomla, foreach

I have the following function, which at the moment is in the default.php file, which I will later on move to the helper.php

```
function getauthor($shouts, $i){
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*')
    ->from('#__users')
    ->where('name = '. $shouts[$i]->name);
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $i=0;
    foreach ($rows as $row){
        $author[$i]->id = $row->id;
        $author[$i]->name = $row->name;
        $i++;
    }
    return $author;
}
```

Basically what I want to do is, print `$author[$i]->name`, but every time I try and do this using the following code:

```
print stripslashes($author[$i]->name);
```

I get the following errors:

```
Undefined variable: author in C:\wamp\www\Joomla25\modules\mod_xxx\tmpl\default.php on line 98

Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\Joomla25\modules\mod_xxx\tmpl\default.php on line 98

Cannot redeclare getauthor() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\Joomla25\modules\mod_xxx\tmpl\default.php:60) in C:\wamp\www\Joomla25\modules\mod_xxx\tmpl\default.php on line 60
```

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong and how to print `$author[$i]->name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the variable `author` defined in the place where you call:

```
print stripslashes($author[$i]->name);
```

In the smallest possible example:

```
$author = getauthor(....)
...
print stripslashes($author[$i]->name);
```

Comment: To explain further, this is an issue of variable scope - the `$author` inside your function only exists as long as the execution is _inside the function_. as soon as the function finishes executing, it's lost